# "The system cannot find the file specified" error for CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, vbscript

Trying to run a vbscript which uses Excel 2016. When I try to create an Excel object with this code

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

The system returns the following error in a message box:

Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
Code: 80070002
Source: (null)

The problem appeared after upgrade of MS Office from 2013 to 2016. Office 2013 was uninstalled and then 2016 was installed.

There was no problems just before Office upgrade.

It looks as Excel.Application is not correctly corresponding to the new Excel 2016.

I tried to change the code like this:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application.16")
```

but still the error is the same